# function in a Button in tkinter

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tkinter

How do I store the value you enter in a dict. The output is
`{'Player name': 'Enter your player name: '}  1`
at the moment and the if statement is just to check if the name is in the dictionary or not, I'll delete it when the problem is fixed. Here is where I'm stuck:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

playerData = {}

p_name = Entry(root, width=50)
p_name.pack()
p_name.insert(0, "Enter your player name: ")


def storeName(x):
    store = x
    playerData.update(Player name=store)

printName = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=storeName(p_name.get()))
printName.pack()

if len(playerData) != 0 or len(playerData):
    print(playerData)
    print(len(playerData))

root.mainloop()
```

I saw it's better to have a function like `storeName(x)` then using global variables. But I don't know how to use it in a button because you don't have the () after the function or is that no problem?

I also tried this:

```
global playerData
playerData = {}
```

and

```
def storeName():
    store = p_name.get()
    playerData.update(Playername=store)
    return store, playerData


printName = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=storeName)
printName.pack()

if len(playerData) != 0:
    print(playerData)
```

there is no output
btw I'm new to tkinter and I'm following a tuturial on positioning in grid, buttons and input fields

Comment: the bottom code also has `root.mainloop()` and `p_name = Entry(root, width=50)`...

Comment: The command for a button shouldn't take any arguments. It should just be `playerData.update(Player_name=p_name.get())` Inside `storeName`

Comment: Your last snippet seems best. Perhaps you should move the `print()` to inside the `storeName()` function.

Comment: @Tomerikoo thx, it's for the first code right?

Comment: @quamrana thx, so everything else stays the same?

Comment: Sorry yes I didn't notice there was another version. As quamrana mentioned, if you expect those `print`s to happen, it will not work. The check for `if len(playerData) != 0:` is done before the main loop so it will never be true. If you want that check to be at runtime (of the loop), put it in `storeName` as recommended by quamrana

Comment: @Tomerikoo thx for the explenation